# Group redundant objects into array js

Tags: javascript, group-by

I have a list of Cards :

```
"Cards": [
        {
          "BIN": "308103",
          "TIER": {
            "Nums": "1",
            "Phone": "111111111 *",
          }
        },
        {
          "BIN": "308103",
          "TIER": {
            "Nums": "2",
            "Phone": "0000000000",
          }
        },
        {
          "BIN": "308516",
          "TIER": {
            "Nums": "",
            "Phone": "00000000 *",
          }
        },
]
```

What i need to do is merge all cards having similair **BIN** into the attribute **TIER** of the first object in the list.

The requested output is :

```
"Cards": [
    {
      "BIN": "308103",
      "TIER": [
      {
        "Nums": "1",
        "Phone": "111111111 *",
      },
      {
        "Nums": "2",
        "Phone": "0000000000",
      }
    ],
  },
  {...}
```

I did it using combined loops into each other but i want a performance-friendly solution.

Comment: What is our definition of similar? This is important for the configuration and logic

Comment: If you have working code and you want something more efficient, SO is not the right place to ask and you might be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - Stackoverflow is here to help you solve code problems, so if you _have_ code that you tried to write for doing what you describe, and it doesn't work, you'll want to [update your post](/help/how-to-ask) to reflect that. Although given what you're asking for, I'd strongly recommend you search SO first, because you're not the first person to need to remap objects in an array, and answers for this _definitely_ already exist on SO.

Comment: Combined loops are very performance friendly, why don't you show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `BIN` by destructing each item and reducing them by assigning them to a BIN key and then accessing the values of the map.

```js
const data = {
  "Cards": [
    { "BIN": "308103", "TIER": { "Nums": "1", "Phone": "111111111 *" } },
    { "BIN": "308103", "TIER": { "Nums": "2", "Phone": "0000000000"  } },
    { "BIN": "308516", "TIER": { "Nums":  "", "Phone": "00000000 *"  } }
  ]
};

const groupedByBin = {
  Cards: Object.values(data.Cards.reduce((acc, { BIN, TIER: { Nums, Phone }}) =>
    ({ ...acc, [BIN] : { BIN, TIER: [...(acc[BIN]?.TIER ?? []), { Nums, Phone }] }}), {}))};

console.log(groupedByBin);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I get an "Unexpected token ." here : (acc[BIN]?.TIER ?? [])

Comment: @AbdallahJg If your browser does not support the nullish coalescing operator (`??`), replace them with a logical or (`||`).

Answer (score 0):

let's say `cardsArray` was you original array.

```
const binMap = {};

cardsArray.forEach(card => {
    if(binMap[card.BIN])
        binMap[card.BIN].TIER.push(card.TIER);
    else
        binMap[card.BIN] = {
            BIN: card.BIN
            TIER: [ card.TIER ]
        };   
});
const finalArray = Object.values(binMap);
```

with finalArray being the desired output.

Note: Object.values is not accepted in all browsers, so if it doesn't work, you could do some additional steps:

```
const finalArray = [];
Object.keys(binMap).forEach(bin => finalArray.push(binMap[bin]));
```